# Android fragment not available (leading to crash) when DB results are back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an app with 2 fragments. Clicking on first fragment will lead to second fragment which tirggers a DB call(Async) to fetch the details from Firebase DB. The second fragment will be populated with data once the DB call is complete. The issue is when I click the back button on the second fragment while DB call is still in progress. Clicking the back button leads to first fragment which is fine but the app crashes when the DB calls returns (to find that second fragment is no longer available). I am able to precisely see (shown below) which part of the code is throwing the null pointer exception but I need help in understanding what would be the best way to handle this issue.

Code snippet which makes DB call

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DBReference);
Query myQuery = mDatabase.orderByChild("title");

    myQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                ContactItem post =   postSnapshot.getValue(ContactItem.class);

                ContactItem item = new ContactItem();
                item.status = post.getStatus();
                item.title = post.getTitle();
                itemList.add(item);
            }
            // Transaction complete, sending to listener
            dataListener.newDataReceived(itemList);
        }
```

Code snippet in the second Fragment where the callback is received once the DB operation is complete.

```
   public void newDataReceived(ArrayList<ContactItem> itemList) {
    progressCircle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter = new ContactItemAdapter(this.getActivity(), itemList, contactType);
```

Adapter code where Null Pointer exception thrown

```
  public ContactItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactItem> items, String contactType) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataSource = items;
    mDataSourceCopy = new ArrayList<ContactItem>(mDataSource);
    //Null pointer exception is thrown at below line
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    mType = contactType;
  }
```

Comment: Your solution is in your problem. Your async task is in progress and you presses back button, you need to stop the async task first on back button if its still in progress. As you are perfoming some UI task after your async task is completed.

Comment: AsyncTask.cancel() , this is how you can cancel your asyncTask.

Comment: I might have been mistaken in stating it is an Async call. By Async i meant the app is allowing the user to press back button even when the DB call is in progress.

Comment: Do you want back button to work or not?

Comment: then you can override your onBackPressed method and assign some boolean status for your Db call is in progress and prevent user from pressing backButton

Comment: one solution would to cancel your async task when user back presses by overriding the onbackpress method.....

Comment: I would like the back button to be still available but if the code can ignore the callback results if the user the already out of the fragment. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Your _mContext_ getting _null_

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your fragment is added to the activity in your `newDataReceived` method.  You can do this by using `isAdded`, `isDetached` or `isRemoving` in the callback from the fragment.

```
public void newDataReceived(ArrayList<ContactItem> itemList) {
  if(isAdded()){
    progressCircle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adapter = new ContactItemAdapter(this.getActivity(), itemList, contactType);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this further. How do i check whether the fragment is added? isDetached and isRemoving are standard methods?

Comment: They are built into the Fragment class so you should be able to use them in your callback from the DB request.   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()

Comment: Thanks. I have tried printing the states and it rightly captures the state of fragment. I will build the logic around it. Thanks again!